# Free server control panels?

Tags: ubuntu, vps

I'm looking for a control panel to control a VPS (a high end one. don't worry about if the control panel is a resource hog). I have already done a bunch of research on control panels, but I just want to make sure I haven't missed any. The ones I like so far are:

- Webmin (great control panel, but I'd like a software that is better suited to setting up websites for clients)
- ISPConfig (right now I'm testing it, but it looks great so far)

Ones I don't like:

- Kloxo (I'm using Ubuntu. Kloxo does not support Ubuntu)
- DTC
- web://cp
- OpenPanel (I love the interface, but it just doesn't have the variety of features that others have)
- RavenCore (Seems that most of their site is down, so I don't exactly want to trust my server to a defunct project)
- VHCS and IspCP (I don't like either, personally)
- EHCP (seemed way too cluttered)
- Virtualmin

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like Webmin, have you considered [Virtualmin GPL?](http://www.virtualmin.com/download.html) You can upgrade it to Virtualmin Pro if you want more features and support.

Comment: Duh! I forgot about that one! I'll try it as soon as I finish trying out ISPConfig. Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't really like it.

Comment: @Sam: LOL. So you like Webmin, but not Virtualmin. Curious what you didn't like about Virtualmin?

Comment: I just feel like it is less organized... I don't really know what I didn't like. I'm kind of OCD about interfaces and such. It has to be PERFECT or else I can't stand it.

Comment: @Sam: We use Webmin GPL & Pro and I spent a few days tweaking the templates. Once the templates were set, I don't play with the settings too often. Also, some of my clients use Webmin, so the interface feels familiar to them. As far as Look & Feel, I haven't found any free ones that felt right AND didn't goober up the config files for the underlying server parts (aside from Virtualmin).

Comment: All right. I'll try it again and maybe try a different template.

Answer (score 1):

I think those on your list are pretty much it. One left out is [ZPanel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zpanelcp/)

Comment: Probably better as a comment.  (You will be able to comment at 50 Rep).

Comment: Considering that the question was not too good to begin with, I'd say this is a valid answer, and not a comment.